# Singlethreaded OpenSSL - OK to read/write on several ports?

Tags: ssl, openssl, nonblocking

When using OpenSSL in a multithreaded program one needs to implement certain locking callbacks.

When using a singlethreaded program but with nonblocking sockets, do I need to think of this? I mean, is it a prolem if multiple ports are doing SSL_read/write and connect at the same time? COntrast that with a singlethreaded program with blocking swockets where one operation would have to finish beofre the next one.
But with my non blocking app one could try SSL_read and have to call it again and before retrying another connection would also call SSL_read...

Answer (score 1):

It's not a problem to use multiple non-blocking sockets in parallel and do TCP accept, connect and SSL handshake, read, write all at parallel. I'm doing this for years and it is very stable. And since there can be only a single SSL operation at one time you don't need any kind of locking.

Comment: Well there can be several ongoing SSL operations, although only one being executed.

Comment: Yes, but it is not a problem to have several handshakes or transmissions ongoing at the same time. The relevant state is maintained per SSL object.